# TypeError on Cyrillic URL characters?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, get, request

I'm using Jest to test a GET request to a URL that contains Cyrillic characters, but it's giving me the error below:

```
#10 13.98     TypeError [ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS]: Request path contains unescaped characters
#10 13.98 
#10 13.98       at Test.request (node_modules/superagent/src/node/index.js:785:18)
#10 13.98       at Test.Object.<anonymous>.Request.end (node_modules/superagent/src/node/index.js:949:8)
#10 13.98       at Test.end (node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:153:7)
#10 13.98       at node_modules/superagent/src/request-base.js:311:12
#10 13.98       at Test.Object.<anonymous>.RequestBase.then (node_modules/superagent/src/request-base.js:293:31)
#10 13.98
```

My code is:

```
const response = await request.get("hааy.com").expect(200);
```

Where the 'a's are Cyrillic. Any ideas?

Comment: "Request path contains unescaped characters" - I'd say that escaping them properly should work, have you tried that?

Comment: [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) the domain name? `encodeURI("hааy.com")` produces `"h%D0%B0%D0%B0y.com"`. Although. I'd expect that to be done automatically by the library that makes web requests.

Comment: Yep, I just solved this. I had to encodeURI and also use `\u0430` instead of just а.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this in the future, I fixed the issue through doing the following:

```
const response = await request.get(encodeURI("h"+"\u0430"+"ay.com")).expect(200);
```

Comment: I don't think you need the escape sequence here. That just produces a plain Cyrillic "a" character. `"\u0430" === "а"` (the "a" is Cyrillic)